# Remove a specific extension from all the files in a directory

Tags: shell, files, rename

I have a couple of files with ".old" extension.
How can I remove the ".old" extension without remove the file?

I can do it manually but with more work:

```
mv file1.key.old file1.key
mv file2.pub.old file2.pub
mv file3.jpg.old file3.jpg
mv file4.jpg.old file4.jpg

(etc...)
```

The command will work with other extensions too?

example:

```
mv file1.MOV.mov file1.MOV
mv file2.MOV.mov file2.MOV
mv file3.MOV.mov file3.MOV

(etc...)
```

or better:

```
mv file1.MOV.mov file1.mov
mv file2.MOV.mov file2.mov
mv file3.MOV.mov file3.mov

(etc...)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [bash's parameter substitution mechanism](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) to remove matching suffix pattern:

```
for file in *.old; do
    mv -- "$file" "${file%%.old}"
done
```

Comment: This: `for file in *.old; do     mv "$file" "${file%%.old}"; done` worked, Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You didn't say what operating system you are using, but many Linux distributions have a `rename` command that you can use for this. There are actually two quite different `rename` commands - Debian and similar systems supply one while RedHat and similar supply another - but either one will work here.

Perl based `rename` on Debian, Ubuntu etc, see: [prename manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html).

Util-Linux `rename` on Redhat etc, see: [rename manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html).

On Debian and similar you can do:

```
rename 's/\.old$//' *
```

or:

```
rename s/.MOV.mov/.mov/ *.*
```

On Redhat and similar you can do:

```
rename .old "" *
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of multi rename tools like http://file-folder-ren.sourceforge.net/

But I think the fastest way to rename is a simple script like:

```
for i in *.old
do
   mv -- "$i" "${i%.old}"
done
```

Note there is no error checking and if the target file exists it might be overwritten.

Comment: Add quotes, one space can ruin everything.

Answer (score 4):

With zsh, first load the [zmv](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) function with

```
autoload zmv
```

(you can do this from your `.zshrc`) then run

```
zmv -w '*.old' '$1'
```

or

```
zmv '(*).old' '$1'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict answers to shell (Bash) programming (rather than using a renaming tool), try this:

```
for oldname in *.old ; do
    newname="${oldname%%.old}"
    if [ -e "$newname" ] ; then
        echo "Cannot rename $oldname because $newname exists." >&2
    else
        mv -- "$oldname" "$newname"
    fi
done
```

I use quotes around `$oldname` and `$newname` because filenames can contain blanks.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming "file" **does not contain a "."** :

```
ls -1 | while read line; do mv "$line" "`echo $line | cut -d'.' -f1,2`"; done
```

This example splits the filename by period and with `-f` you can control the fields to keep.

For your third example, you would use:

```
ls -1 | while read line; do mv "$line" "`echo $line | cut -d'.' -f1,3`"; done
```

Comment: If your folder contains files that are not to be renamed, add `| grep <pattern> ` after `ls -1`

Comment: This removed more than I expected in file sub.class1.server.ca.pem.old become sub.class1 instead sub.class1.server.ca.pem   Thanks

Comment: If it removed more than you expected, you failed to read the first line of my answer: _assuming "file" does not contain a ._

Comment: `ls | while read line; do …` has no advantage over `for line in *; do …` and the downside of breaking over various file names. [Do not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score -1):

"Refinement" of Christian's solution ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180275 ) using rev:

```
ls -1 | while read line; do mv "$line" "`echo $line | rev | cut -d'.' -f2- | rev`"; done
```

Comment: See: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/21471)